# Is it possible to create a LAN between two notebooks via BlueTooth/Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, netbook, lan, ad-hoc-network

In a given place there are two notebooks—[HP Mini 210-1060BR](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02066941&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001) and [HP Mini 210-1040BR](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Mini-210-PC-series/4075896/model/4126174/drivers)—no existent Wi-Fi connections available, no cable, both bluetooth enabled. What I want is to create a real LAN between the two, and—depending on how fast would that be—transfer files, play games, etc.

*Alternatively* I’d like to know if there's another way to do the same thing with no additional devices.

Details:

1. Both notebooks are Bluetooth capable.
2. Both are Wi-Fi capable.
3. Both are realtively new (made in 2010).
4. Both have 10/100 ethernet cable ports (though I don’t want to use it).
5. Both are netbooks (but that doesn’t change much).
6. Both are HP Mini’s: [HP Mini 210-1060BR](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02066941&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001) and [HP Mini 210-1040BR](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Mini-210-PC-series/4075896/model/4126174/drivers).
7. We are willing to install third party applications.
8. Battery life is not a major concern (both have 6-cell batterys)  .
9. Both are using Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: Use wifi if you can, it's much faster than bluetooth (and easier to setup)

Comment: Not to be overly sticky on terminology, but with Bluetooth you would call it a "PAN" or Personal Area Network.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an adhoc network and for this work you have these 2 choices:

#### Install a Wifi Hotspot app on one of them

You can install a wifi hotspot app on one of them and then create a hotspot and connect from the other. There are plenty of these softwares but I myself prefer to use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) which has the best compatibility and is best among the other alternatives .

#### Do it with windows itself

You can create an ad-hoc network with windows itself, all you have to do is to follow the instructions made here: [for Windows 7](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot) , [for Windows 8 and 8.1](http://lifehacker.com/turn-a-windows-8-1-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-the-com-1593327340)

Also aside from all of these I recommend you to use a third party device such as a phone and by creating hotspot with phone and then connect both 2 laptops to this hotspot. This is better and you will fall into less/no problems (as my experience says).

Comment: To be clear, a hotspot, and an ad-hoc network are two completely different things - one cannot be another.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is called an Ad-Hoc network. They arent terribly complex to set up. Heres an article from microsoft doing exactly what you're looking for

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7